# Unable to set #default_value for a date field

Tags: 8, forms

I have a form with a date field.

```
$form['filter_dates']['start_date'] = [
    '#type' => 'date',
    '#title' => $this->t('From'),
    '#description' => $this->t('Start event date'),
    '#default_value' => [
        'year' => 2015, 'month' => 05, 'day' => '09',
    ]
];
```

But when the form is displayed the date field doesn't contain the value "09.05.2015". The date field is empty.

Could you clarify me, how can I fill the date field with the value ?
I watched it as on my form as on the examle form from the Examples module.

Answer (score 1):

Set it like this

```
$form['filter_dates']['start_date'] = [
    '#type' => 'date',
    '#title' => $this->t('From'),
    '#description' => $this->t('Start event date'),
       '#default_value' => [
        '2015-05-09',
    ]
];
```

Comment: I did like "#default_value" => '2015-05-09',
It works.
But why it is written about year, month and day in Drupal API ?
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Date.php/class/Date/8.2.x

Comment: I created an issue some time ago here about the documentation being wrong: https://www.drupal.org/node/2836530